# assembly max and min procedure not producing expected result

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to write an assembly program that finds the min and max of an array using a procedure (max_min). The array ends with a zero telling the program the end of the array has been reached.

The results should be as follows:
for Numbers DW 3,4,5,2,6,0 
max:6
min:2

However the result I receive is
max 6:
min 0:

Lp2 - loop 2 is supposed to find the minimum and it should give 2 as a result. However, it doesn't, it gives 0 as the result. How do I correct this so that I get 2 as the minimum?

```
%include "io.mac"
.STACK 100H 

.DATA
   Numbers DW 3,4,5,2,6,0
   msg1  db "Max",0
   msg2  db "Min",0

.CODE
.STARTUP
    call max_min

    nwln
    PutStr msg1
    nwln
    PutInt ax
    nwln
    PutStr msg2
    nwln
    PutInt bx
    done:
.EXIT

max_min:
    mov si, Numbers ;point to array
    mov ax, si
lp1:
    cmp word [si],0  
    je next
    add si,2
    cmp ax, [si]        
    jl max

continue:
    jmp lp1

next:
    mov si, Numbers ;point to array
    mov bx, si
lp2:
    cmp word [si],0  
    je complete
    add si,2
    cmp bx, [si]        
    jg min
go:
    jmp lp2

max:
    mov ax, [si]  ;keep track of max
    jmp continue

min:
    mov bx, [si]  ;keep track of min
    PutInt[si]
    jmp go

complete:
    ret
```

Comment: It should return 0 by the logic you wrote. You correct it by writing code, which does search for minimal value in array.

Comment: Numerous issues here.  You check 0 too often and in interesting locations (usually against old data).  You also appear to be throwing away ax/bx values upon entering into next: and max_min.  Instead, consider this.  Your first time through code should establish ax/bx to the first entry of Numbers array and then exit if 0, otherwise increment array.  After that, main loop should check for 0, check min, check max, increment array.  Use calls or direct jumps if you wish to enter and exit from min/max checks in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am committing a grave sin here - blind coding one of my weaker assembler languages without compiling/assembling or testing.  Please use this as a reference to my above comment on how to organize your code in a simpler to understand and maintain format.  Even if there are bugs here, it demonstrates the idea of breaking up the code into manageable chunks and use of comments to explain what is going on. (Editorial note: x86 assembler is ugly! I want my ARM code back :)  )

```
max_min:
    mov si, Numbers ;point to array

    ; Set Min/Max to first array entry and exit if value is 0
    mov ax, [si]
    mov bx, [si]
    cmp word [si],0  
    je  done

    ; Increment to next value
    add si,2

main_loop:
    ; if number is 0, we are done
    cmp word [si],0  
    je done

    ; if number is greater than or equal to max, don't assign to ax
    cmp ax, [si]        
    jge not_max

    mov ax, [si]

not_max:
    ; if number is less than or equal to min, don't assign to bx
    cmp bx, [si]        
    jle not_min

    mov bx, [si]

not_min:
    ; Next array entry and loop
    add si,2
    jmp main_loop

done:
    ret
```